# $ T $ is normal if and only if for every $ T $-invariant subspace, its orthogonal complement is also $ T $-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> **Proposition:** Suppose that $ V $ is a complex vector space and $ \dim(V) < \infty $. Then $ T \in \mathcal{L}(V) $ is normal if and only if the orthogonal complement of every $ T $-invariant subspace is $ T $-invariant.

I hope that you can help me with a solution or a hint. Thanks.

**My idea:**

The forward implication: If $ T $ is normal, then $ T^{*} = p(T) $ for any polynomial $ p \in \Bbb{C}[X] $. Then given a $ T $-invariant subspace $ U $, we know that $ U $ is $ p(T) $-invariant. In other words, $ U $ is $ T^{*} $-invariant. As $ U $ is $ T^{*} $-invariant, it follows that $ W \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} U^{\perp} $ is $ (T^{*})^{*} $-invariant. Hence, $ W $ is $ T $-invariant.

I was unable to work out the backward implication.

Comment: I managed to make the first implication.

Comment: Great. Can you include your proof, in detail, in your post?

Comment: Why all these demands ?

Comment: yes, of course Pedro.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus If the OP is explicit about what he has already proven, he won't get answers telling him things he already knows. If he posts his attempts, he will get better hints based on his ideas, &c.

Comment: If $T$ is normal, then $T^\ast =p(T)$ for **any** polynomial...?

Comment: any $p(x) \in C[X]$ where $C$ is complex field. This is true.

Comment: @João: Not true. The identity operator $ I $ is normal, but how can $ I = 2 I $?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use for a normal operator $||Tv|| = ||T^*v||$. What does this tell you when you apply this on the matrix induced by $T$

Comment: I thought about it but did not get anywhere.

Comment: Any vector space $V = U + U'$ where $U'$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$. Now, $U$ is given to be invariant under a linear mapping $T$. Can you write the matrix induced by $T$ now. 

Now use that $||Tv||=||T^*v||$. Can you visualize something?

Comment: What will the product of the matrices induced by $T$ and $T^*$ look like?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it.

Comment: You should also take into account that for an orthonormal basis, the matrix induced by $T$ and $T*$ are the conjugate transposes of each other. you might want to look up Linear Algebra done right by sheldon axler.

Comment: @VHP Your hint seems to be relevant only for the already proved implication (if $T$ is normal, then ...). The question is about the converse.

Comment: @Etienne for an orthonormal basis, matrix induced by $T$ and $T^*$ are conjugate transposes of each other, and any $v=U \oplus U'$. I believe this should give the desired result?

Comment: yess, but I like to make sure it was right ..

Comment: I hope you get it :-)

Comment: @VHP Read again your hint: "for a normal operator ...". And also your first comment: "Now use that $\Vert Tv\Vert=\Vert T^*v\Vert$. Here, you don't know that $T$ is normal; this is what you want to prove.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $T$ will have at least one eigenvector since the ground field is algebraically closed. If $v$ is a $T$ eigenvector and $W\perp \{v\}$ then for $w \in W$,

$$(T^*v,w)=(v,Tw)=0$$ so in fact $T^*v$ is orthogonal to $W$ and thus $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$ also. It is now easy to see that $W$ is $T^*$ invariant  and the same assumptions about $T$ hold restricted to $W$, now by induction $T$ is normal restricted to $W$ and this gives that $T$ is normal.

Or better the assumptions imply that $T$ is diagonalizabe by the argument I gave.

Comment: But I don´t know if T is diagonalizable or not.

Comment: What is your ground field ?

Comment: complex field..

Comment: I don't understand.. Can you be more especific? Because, we now assume that every complement ortoghonal of subspace T-invariante is T-invariant. Why this implies that T is normal?

Comment: @João Read again Rene's answer, especially the end of it. What he shows is that the assumption on $T$ implies that $T$ is diagonalizable in some orthonormal basis; which obviously implies that $T$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $T^*=p(T)$ for **any** polynomial in $\mathbb{C}(X)$. However, there exists polynomials $p$ in $\mathbb{C}(X)$ such that $p(T)=T^*$. It suffices to take a polynomial which maps any eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ in $\bar{\lambda}$. The interpolation polinomial will do that...